How to assign MemoryStream to a custom class that inherits from MemoryStream
I have class MemoryStream2 that inherits from MemoryStream, the only difference is that it introduces a new variable - reference id. Now I have a situation where a certain function returns MemoryStream and I need to convert/assign it to MemoryStream2.
public class MemoryStream2 : System.IO.MemoryStream
{
    public string ReferenceId = "";
    public MemoryStream2() : base() { }
    public MemoryStream2(byte[] buffer) : base(buffer) { }
    public MemoryStream2(System.IO.MemoryStream ms)
    {

        this.ReferenceId = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        this = ms;
    }
}

However, (System.IO.MemoryStream)this = ms; is an error:

Cannot assign to 'this' because it is read-only

(System.IO.MemoryStream)this = ms; is also incorrect:

The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

So how do I do this? How do I assign a standard MemoryStream to a custom one, preferably without reloading/copying data from one stream to another?
Thank you
EDIT: Doesn't looks like my problem has a quick solution. Composition looks like the best solution so far, even though that requires some code refactoring.

It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have. This kinda sounds like an XY problem.

Are you looking for ms.CopyTo(this)? You might want to set the position of ms and this to 0 before and after (respectively) the call. That said, this does look like an XY Problem as Progman said. Why not just create a MemoryStream wrapper class instead of inserting from it?

Now I have a situation where a certain function returns MemoryStream Why not change that function to return MemoryStream2 instead?

If an object is an actual MemoryStream there is no way to "convert" it to MemoryStream2 after creation. You need to create a new object.

You should ask yourself if inheritance is the right solution to your problem. Why not composition?

@mjwills Cannot return MemoryStream2, the function that returns MS is in a different project and has no understanding of what MS2 is. I can't even add a reference to that project where MS2 is defined because then it already referencing the project where function that returns MS is - this would create a circular reference.

@KlausGütter aye, thats what im going for now. Thank you

Composition is almost certainly a better alternative than inheritance. I.e.
public class MemoryStream2(MemoryStream Stream, string ReferenceId)
{
    public MemoryStream2(MemoryStream stream) : this(stream, DateTime.Now.ToString()){}
}

You could also use value tuples to create pairs of data without creating a new explicit type, i.e. (MemoryStream Stream, string ReferenceId). Inheritance has several downsides, including a strong coupling to the base class, so in most situations composition is preferred.
You could use the delegate pattern. This can be a useful pattern, but is most suitable for fairly small interfaces. It is not really suited for MemoryStream since it is not really designed to be inherited. It could be used with Stream but this is also not ideal due to the large number of methods:
public class MemoryStream2(MemoryStream Stream, string ReferenceId) : Stream
{
    public MemoryStream2(MemoryStream stream) : this(stream, DateTime.Now.ToString()){}
    public override void Flush() => Stream.Flush();
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => Stream.Seek(offset, origin);
    public override void SetLength(long value) => Stream.SetLength(value);
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => Stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => Stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    public override bool CanRead => Stream.CanRead;
    public override bool CanSeek => Stream.CanSeek;
    public override bool CanWrite => Stream.CanWrite;
    public override long Length => Stream.Length;
    public override long Position
    {
        get => Stream.Position;
        set => Stream.Position = value;
    }
}

If absolutely necessary you could extract the backing buffer and use this as the buffer for your new stream, But this is not something I would recommend since GetBuffer may fail:
public class MemoryStream2 : MemoryStream
{
    public string ReferenceId = "";

    public MemoryStream2(MemoryStream stream) : base(stream.GetBuffer())
    {
        this.SetLength(stream.Length);
        this.Position = stream.Position;
        this.ReferenceId = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}

You could also copy the data from the existing stream, but it seem rather unnecessary to create a full copy of all the data just to associate it with a reference id.

I was trying to avoid code refactoring, but seems that my problem does not have an easy (no code refactoring) solution. I will work on composition, seems that is the best approach to my problem. Thank you for your very detailed answer.
